# PyDev interpreter indication within USB drive

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm using PortableApps application with portable eclipse and portable python installed. I've equipped my eclipse with PyDev plugin enabling me to run and debug my files on whatever windows-based platform I'd like. The problem is in order to use the interpreter inside my USB stick, I need to address the proper location of the python interpreter in PyDev settings. with USB drive connected to different computers, I get different drive letter for my USB stick which would make problem locating the path of the installed python inside my USB stick.
Is there any way to enforce eclipse's PyDev plugin to look for python interpreter which is installed inside my USB permanently?!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered giving the interpreter location as a relative path? For example:
`..\..\..\python\python.exe`. I am not sure what the working directory of PyDev is, but if you put enough `..` in, Windows will stop at the drive root.

Comment: I have not! but the thing is if you'd be familiar with PyDev plugin inside eclipse, it requires the full path of the external interpreter like Python as if it pops up the location finder. 
Have you tried it yourself? I mean I believe it'll work if there was an .ini file to provide the path, but in this case! I'm afraid that solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use subst? You can config with some letter like Z: or X: and in any computed that you plug your pen drive, you just run a .bat with the subst and your environment is ready ...

Answer (score 0):

use a relative eclipse path variable like:
{eclipse_home}..\..\..\PortablePython\App\python.exe

Answer (score 0):

I put my portable Eclipse under version control. Then I initialized the interpreter settings. In the commit preview it's possible to see that the altered settings are stored in

> workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.python.pydev.prefs

I replaced the absolute paths with relative ones (as already stated by other answers) using search/replace, e.g.

```
D\:\\EclipsePython\\App  => {eclipse_home}\\..\\App\
```

and restarted Eclipse after saving the settings file.

The interpreter settings dialog of PyDev shows the relative paths (also for the library paths that can not be edited directly). (If a popup asks you to apply detected changes, choose to ignore them.)

I am able to run my python program with that portable settings.

[image]