# Eclipse, PyDev "Project interpreter not specified”

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, interpreter

I have installed PyDev in eclipse Luna. After successful installation of PyDev, when I want to create a new project I get the error: 
Project interpreter not specified

How can I fix it? There is no option for interpreter to choose from.

eclipse version Luna,
Mac OSX Yosemite,
PyDev latest version (installed according to http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html)

[image]

Comment: Do you have Python installed on your machine? If yes, then in Eclipse->Window->Preferences->Interpreter-Python. Either do a Auto Config or manually configure your Python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks @sk11. It solved my issue. I had python installed.

Comment: As a note, from that same window you could click the hyperlink "Please configure an interpreter before proceeding." to do that...

Comment: I had the same issue. On Mac OS X the path is a little bit different and I had to go to "Eclipse -> preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreter -> Python interpreter" and then search for the python version, according to [this link](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html). Thanks to homebrew, it is in /usr/local/**cellar**/ where I could choose between 2.X or 3.X. If you don't use homebrew they'll be on /user/local/bin/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In my case it has worked with following steps

Prerequisite: Python should be installed

1. Go to Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreters and click on "Python Interpreter".
2. Then click on new button and add python executable location.

> Example for windows:
>
> ```
> c:\python2.7\python.exe
> ```
>
> example for ubuntu:
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/python
> ```

3. Then you can attached image and click on finish.

[It should work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VLGK.png)

Comment: If you want to use a relative path tot he python interpreter (e.g. for usage on usb stick) you can manually insert the relative path in a settings file. Also see my related answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623771/pydev-interpreter-indication-within-usb-drive/18883477

Answer (score 2):

On my Mac 10.11.3, using LiClipse 2.5.3 I solved it with these steps:

Open a terminal window and type `which python`

In my case it replied with `/usr/bin/python`

Calling python it informed me I was using version 2.7.10.

Next I called LiClipse and went LiClipse -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreter -> New

For "Interpreter Name" I used "Python 2.7.10", although I am aware that is just a sym link and it could be updated any time.
For "Interpreter Executable" I entered "/usr/bin/python"

Then "Ok"

After that, the error message went away.

[image: setting python interpreter location]

Answer (score 0):

In my windows system python executable installed path is C:\tools\python2\python.exe.

as mentioned above 
Go to eclipse Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreters and click on "Python Interpreter" and pointed the python executable path.